# Profile picture in cell not updating correctly

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a PFQueryTableViewController populated by comments from different users. Each user has a profile picture stored on the Parse database. After loading each comment into a cell, I query the PFUser class to retrieve the profile picture of the user who posted the comment and add it to the cell. I also use PFCachePolicy to cache the profile picture to the device's memory so that displaying new cells with new profile pictures is a smoother transition.

However this is not the case. When a user posts a new comment and a new cell is added, the profile pictures shuffle around and takes about two seconds or so to update with the right image (probably because the table is re-queried and updated). I am trying to achieve something similar to iMessage or WhatsApp where the profile picture remained 'fixed' in the cell.

I am not sure what the problem is or if there is a better way to do this?

```
    // get objectId of the user who posted a comment
    let senderId = object?["Users"]!.objectId as String!

    // query PFUser class using senderId to retrieve profile picture
    var senderImage:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    senderImage.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
    senderImage.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(senderId){
        (sender: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && sender?.objectForKey("profilePicture") != nil {
            let thumbnail = sender?.objectForKey("profilePicture") as? PFFile
            thumbnail?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    imageView.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                } else {
                    println(error)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not waiting until the images are finished loading when you update the UIImageView. Try Using this code:

```
     var query = PFQuery(className:"Users")


            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    // The find succeeded.
                    self.scored = objects!.count
                    // Do something with the found objects
                    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                        for object in objects {




                            let userImageFile = object["Image"] as! PFFile
                            userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                                if error == nil {
                                    if let imageData = imageData {
                                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)

                                        self.imageArray.append(image!)

                                    }
                                }



                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                   //don't reload image view here! 
                                }

                            }





                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Log details of the failure
                    print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                 //wait until here to reload the image view

if self.imageArray.isEmpty == false {
//image array is not empty

    self.ImageView.image = imageArray.first

}
else {
//no images found in parse
}



            }
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out now. Is imageArray just an NSArray?

Comment: I've done the following 

`class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {
        
    var imageArray: [AnyObject] = []`

Then in :

            `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                // wait until here to reload the image view
                imageView.image = self.imageArray[0] as? UIImage
            }`

But this crashes...

Comment: The error occurs at this line 

`imageView.image = self.imageArray[0] as? UIImage`

I did a backtrace and this is what I got: 

(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0xd802d, 0x000000010358bfa7 Comment`Comment.TableViewController.(tableView (Comment.TableViewController) -> (ObjectiveC.UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath, object : Swift.Optional<ObjectiveC.PFObject>) -> ObjectiveC.PFTableViewCell).(closure #1).(closure #2) [inlined] generic specialization <Swift.AnyObject> of Swift.Array._checkSubscript <A>(Swift.Array<A>)(Swift.Int) -> () at TableViewController.swift:0

Comment: See Updated Code In Answer.